# Guidelines for high-throughput low-latency unary calls in gRPC

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

I'm looking for guidelines to maximize throughput and minimize latency for gRPC unary calls. I need to achieve about 20,000 QPS, < 50ms each. On a moderate hardware (4 core CPU) I could only achieve about 15K QPS with an average latency of 200ms. I'm using Java client and server. The server does nothing except return a response. The client sends multiple concurrent requests using an async stub. The number of concurrent requests is limited.CPU remains in the ~80% range. 
In comparison, using Apache Kafka I can achieve much higher throughput (100's of thousands QPS), as well as latency in the 10ms range.

Comment: gRPC's [benchmarking suite](https://grpc.io/docs/guides/benchmarking/) shows 195µs latency (for single RPC) and 245k QPS for an 8 core GCE VM, using TLS. There are a lot of factors that can impact results, but the most basic are the type of benchmark, amount of warmup, and the network. Your numbers are so far away from expected, I would generally assume this is because there was no warmup period to give time for the JIT to optimize the code, but that's shooting in the dark.

Comment: Thanks @EricAnderson. I'm now running both client/server on AWS r4.2xlarge instances. I'm getting much better throughput - 50K (after warmup) with low latencies as expected. The client is single threaded. Both client/server instances are at ~200% CPU (two threads utilized). How can I squeeze out more performance?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using grpc-java 1.21 or later and `grpc-netty-shaded` you should already be using the Netty Epoll transport. If you are using `grpc-netty`, add a runtime dependency on `io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll` (the correct version can be found by looking at `grpc-netty`'s pom.xml or by the [version table in SECURITY.md](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/SECURITY.md#netty)).

The default executor for callbacks is a "cached thread pool." If you do not block (or know the limits of your blocking), specifying a fixed-size thread pool can increase performance. You can try both `Executors.newFixedThreadPool` and `ForkJoinPool`; we've seen the "optimal" choice vary depending on the work load. You specify your own executor via `ServerBuilder.executor()` and `ManagedChannelBuilder.executor()`.

If you have high throughput (~Gbps+ per client with TLS; higher if plaintext) using multiple Channels can improve performance by using multiple TCP connections. Each TCP connection is pinned to a Thread, so having more TCP connections allows using more Threads. You can create the multiple Channels and then round-robin over them; selecting a different one for each RPC. Note that you can easily implement the `Channel` interface to "hide" this complexity from the rest of your application. This looks like it would provide you specifically with a large gain, but I put it last because it's commonly not necessary.

Comment: You can consider [this ChannelPool](https://github.com/googleapis/gax-java/blob/master/gax-grpc/src/main/java/com/google/api/gax/grpc/ChannelPool.java) as an example. Note that it is longer than strictly necessary because it implements ManagedChannel instead of Channel.